# android- Retrofit 1.9 - posting data returns invalid JSON for LoginActivity

Tags: android, json, post, gson

I doing something wrong related with sending login information to server. I tried lots of way to access "isSuccessful: true" thing but i failed.

---

Retrofit Error Message:

```
*D/Retrofit:*

{"IsSuccessfull":false,"IncidentId":"de3d","Messages":
[{"Key":"ExceptionResponse","Value":"SOME_ERRORS_OCCURED_DURING_EXECUTION"},>{"Key":"Exception","Value":"ServiceExecutor.InvalidApplication"}]}*

*D/Retrofit: 
<--- END HTTP (224-byte body)*
```

---

Server get the Json with this way:

```
    {
      UserName:'fatih.kaya',
      Password:'11111',    
      AuthProvider:'1'
    }
```

and should returns this:

```
    {
      "Data": {something},
      "IsSuccessfull": true
    }
```

---

```
private void serviceWithHeaderTask() {
        showProgress();

        JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonParams.put("UserName", "fatih.kaya");
            jsonParams.put("Password", "11111");
            jsonParams.put("AuthProvider", "1");

            // jsonMain.put("function", "login");
            jsonMain.put("parameters", jsonParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


        /** convert sample json to retrofit typedString **/
        TypedString parm = new TypedString(jsonMain.toString());
        // service call
        serviceWithHeader.postJsonString(parm, new Callback<Object>() {


            @Override
            public void success(Object object, Response response) {

                String responseString = new Gson().toJson(object);
                showSnackBar(responseString);

                hideProgress();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                retrofitError.printStackTrace();

                showSnackBar("Error:"+retrofitError.getMessage());
                hideProgress();
            }
        });
    }

***RestInterface***

    public interface RestInterface {

        @POST("/auth/signin")
        void postJsonString(@Body TypedString string, Callback<Object> cb);
    }


***ServiceGenerator***

    public class ServiceGenerator {

        public static final String BASE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/api/json/";

        public static class SessionRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.addHeader("x-Application-Key", "PIRLWjnl");
            }
        }


        public static <S> S createServiceWithJsonHeader(Class<S> serviceClass) {
            RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor());

            RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
            adapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
            return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

Comment: is that the json response from your server??

Comment: @SripadRaj when I use post man with using header and body as this: http://i.imgur.com/S0CvXwX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this part

```
TypedString parm = new TypedString(jsonMain.toString());
```

with this:

```
TypedString parm = new TypedString(jsonParams.toString());
```

and it worked. so the `parameters` word is unnecessary to add.

thanks people who tried to help =)

Answer (score 0):

It is much more convenient to use Gson and jsonschema2pojo.org instead of manually parsing Json

Comment: I already have pojos from that website, but I will use pojos after I create the valid connection

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit (before 2.0) comes with (I think is Gson) as default JSON Parser so the only thing you should change is:

```
serviceWithHeader.postJsonString(parm, new Callback<LoginResponse>() { //This is the key ingredient
/* implementation */
}
```

and then you should create LoginReponse class

```
class LoginResponse {
    Object Data;
    Boolean IsSuccessfull;
}
```

After creating these classes and setting it in the callback Type Retrofit should take care of populate these fields.
If you wan't to create these kind of classes from a json response I've created a small script that you may find useful.

https://github.com/Pato94/JsonToJavaConverter

Comment: I replaced that line with the one you wrote, (btw I have LoginModel class which I created before, I thought it would be easier to parse JSON manually to make connection instead of using pojo classes) and set callbackType as LoginModel, it gave me same error response.

Comment: my LoginModel :
public class LoginModel {
(at Sign) SerializedName("Data")
(at Sign)Expose
private Data data;
@SerializedName("IsSuccessfull")
@Expose
private Boolean isSuccessfull;
 public Data getData() {
return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Boolean getIsSuccessfull() {
        return isSuccessfull;
    }
    public void setIsSuccessfull(Boolean isSuccessfull) {
        this.isSuccessfull = isSuccessfull;
    }


}


and thank you for your script i will try it =)

Comment: After a second read I'm seeing that you're generating the following.
{
  "parameters": {
    /*Here is the json you actually want to send*/
  }
}

Maybe you should try creating a class for the request body and send it as:
void postJsonString(@Body LoginRequest request, Callback<Object> cb);

just to clarify:
class LoginRequest {
  String UserName;
  ...more fields
}